# How do I change the bounds of a LpVariable in PuLP dynamically?

Tags: python, pulp

I've initialised my LpVariable like so:

```
x = LpVariable('x', None, None)
```

At this point, my variable has upper and lower bounds as `float('inf')` and `float('-inf')`. Now based on some parameters of my logic, I want to bound the upper limit of this variable to, say, any `x < 20`.

Can I only do this by adding in an LpProblem and modifying the Variable using the problem parameters?

```
y = LpProblem('Minimizing Problem', LpMinimize) 
y += x < 20
```

Or is there another way to manipulate the variable? Changing `x.upBound` doesn't seem to work. I can still set invalid integers/floats as the solution (ie. `values > 20`) and it accepts them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out both ways work. So for the example:

```
y = LpProblem("min", LpMinimize)
y += x + 10  # Objective Function
x = LpVariable('x', None, None)  # set to bounds=[float("-inf"),float("inf")]
```

We can change the lower bound on `x` from the default `float("-inf")` to `20` in one of the following ways:

Option 1: 
Modifying the constraints on the LpProblem. So, for instance, if you wanted to change the `lowBound of x to 20`, you would need to use:

```
y += x > 20, "changing lower bound of x"
```

Option 2: 
Modifying the lowBound attribute on the LpVariable object:

```
x.lowBound = 20
```

Both these changes should give us the solution of `y = 30`

Comment: How about adding new variables to an already existing constraint?  I solved the problem, then want to include some additional variables that were not in the original solve - how can I add those to the obj function and the constraints without having to complete reformulate the problem?

Comment: Can you ask that as a new question and link it in the comments? That's a different question/solution than this one... I'll work up sample code for what you're asking in the meantime.