# How Can I fix the variable value without aditional constrain

Tags: python, pulp

I need to do Fix&Optimize heuristic and I need fix the last value of some variables but without adition constrain because the problem is big and more constrain is worse.

Example that I don't want :

prob.addConstraint(Y[m,j,t,o] == 154,56.

I have the value of initial value in a variable [dict] and use

```
        for k, v in varsdict.items():
            k.setInitialValue(v)
```

for define the value, but need fix almost one.

I use solve>

solver = pulp.CPLEX_CMD(msg=1, mip_start=1, timelimit = '3600')
prob.solve(solver)

thanks community

Comment: It seems that this is unrelated to CPLEX since you are going through pulp. If that is correct, can you please remove the `cplex` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_mip_start.html#fixing-a-variable

```
    for k, v in varsdict.items():
         k.setInitialValue(v)
         k.fixValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly modify the bounds of a variable, see this related question: [How do I change the bounds of a LpVariable in PuLP dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749833/how-do-i-change-the-bounds-of-a-lpvariable-in-pulp-dynamically)

So you can just set lower and upper bound of the variable to the same value and the variable will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks your answer Daniel, i tried this method but the solution change in the heuristic. I have 5 run each fix all variable for  test check and the objetive value is different.                                       for k, v in varsdict.items():
                k.setInitialValue(v) 
                k.lowBound= v
                k.upBound=v                                                                                                                  prob.solve.pulp.CPLEX_CMD(msg=1, timelimit = time_limit)                                                     the solution

Comment: Maybe the models you are solving in the 5 runs are different? Or you solve with a time limit or something? Or the values in `varsdict` are different? To debug this I suggest to export the model for each iteration and compare them. If they are not the same then different solutions are to be expected. If they should be the same but are not then you have to find your place in the code that makes the models different.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks your answer Daniel, i tried this method but the solution change in the heuristic. I have 5 run each fix all variable for  test check and the objetive value is different.

```
   for k, v in varsdict.items():
                k.setInitialValue(v) 
                k.lowBound= v
                k.upBound=v                                                                                                                  prob.solve.pulp.CPLEX_CMD(msg=1, timelimit = time_limit)
```

the solution  is:                                                                                                                                  Run  FO

```
1   202397489,1

2   202397489,1

3   265216100

4   202397489,1

5   265216100
```

Comment: You should remove this answer. It is not an answer but a follow-up. Either extend your question with this or ask this as a comment.